# Solution Verification: Change the order of integration of the following double Integral.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> $\int^{1}_{-1}dx\int^{1-x^2}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}f(x,y)dy$

**My Work:** 
First of all, I wanted to try to draw the domain, so: 
$x=1$, $x=-1$ 
$y=1-x^2$, $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2} \Longrightarrow y^2+x^2=1$ Only for ($y\le 0$) otherwise the equation won't hold. 

Now I can see the domain, in order to integrate in opposite order I must do two integrals when $-1 \le y \le 0$ and $0 \le y \le 1
$. 
Now it's time to find the functions: $y=1-x^2\Longrightarrow x=\pm\sqrt{1-y}$. 
So my first part is $\int^{1}_{0}dy\int^{\sqrt{1-y}}_{-\sqrt{1-y}}f(x,y)dx$. 
In the other part: $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2} \Longrightarrow x^2=1-y^2 \Longrightarrow x=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$ (But only for $y\le 0$). 
So my second integral is: 
$\int^{0}_{-1}dy\int^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}f(x,y)dx$ 

And in the end I add the two integrals together for the result. 
I would appreciate feedback about my work, would love to hear if there's better tricks or if I missed something, thanks in advance!

Comment: That is good work!

Comment: @MathLover Thanks! That's mostly from what I learnt from your answers in the last two questions!